# convert string to callback for use as function parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a bot, and in each of my commands' files I have an execute function in the module.exports, for example: `execute(msg, args)`, I was able to get just the parameters between the brackets in my index.js, and I want to use them to dynamically execute all the functions/variables (and also because I was having problems with the order in which I wrote them for each file) I need in the other file with module.exports. This is my (index.js) code:

```
    const cmd = client.commands.get(command)
    const stringifiedCmd = cmd.execute.toString()

    var firstLine = stringifiedCmd.split('\n')[0]
    // Gets only the first line with the execute function
    var str = firstLine.substring(
        firstLine.lastIndexOf(`(`) + 1,
        firstLine.indexOf(`)`)
        // Outputs msg, args for example 

 cmd.execute(str)
```

However when using the command it doesn't seem to be recognizing the parameters as valid, as they're still a string

EDIT:

If needed, here's an example of how all my commands' files are structured:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'command',
    description: 'description of command',
    execute(msg, args) {

          // code

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a command file? Preferably, also show if each command in `client.commands` is imported using `require`

Comment: I added an example in the question

Answer (score 1):

You got quite far along this solution. Having got everything between the opening and closing parenthesis, you'll want to split out that and trim the results

```
const argsStrings = firstLine.substring(
          firstLine.lastIndexOf(`(`) + 1,
          firstLine.indexOf(`)`)
        ).split(",").map(x => x.trim());
```

Now you have an array of strings representing the args (`["msg","args"]`). Now, where are you going to get the values from? Lets assume for a moment you have a map containing the arg as key, and the value as the arg value - eg

```
const container = { 
     "msg": "Some message", 
     "args": ["foo","bar"] 
};
```

Now, its as easy as calling `apply` on the function passing the values looked up from `container` for each argument

```js
function execute(msg, args) { // Use this method to demo the result

  console.log(msg);
  console.log(args);

}

const stringifiedCmd = execute.toString()
const firstLine = stringifiedCmd.split('\n')[0]
const argsStrings = firstLine.substring(
          firstLine.lastIndexOf(`(`) + 1,
          firstLine.indexOf(`)`)
        ).split(",").map(x => x.trim());
        

const container = { "msg":"Some message", "args":["foo","bar"] }

execute.apply(this, argsStrings.map(a => container[a]))
```

Caveat: The only thing you might want to watch out for is there is nothing in javascript stopping you splitting the args of a function accross multiple lines

```
function thisIsValid(
   arg1,
   arg2
){
   // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jamiec's answer, he cited the problem with writing params in different lines. To solve this, instead of splitting the function's first line, you can instead split the function prototype section using the `}` character:

```js
const stringfiedFunc = execute.toString();

const funcPrototype = stringfiedFunc.substring(0, stringfiedFunc.lastIndexOf('{')); // gets the prototype section of the function

const paramsArr = funcPrototype.substring(
    funcPrototype.lastIndexOf('(') + 1, funcPrototype.indexOf(')')) // gets the between parenthesis part
  .split(',') // separate each param using ,
  .map(x => x.trim()); // map will put each part in an array after trimming white spaces
```

The importance of slicing the first line or prototype is that no other parenthesis that may be inside the function messes with the parenthesis indexes used on `paramsArr`